# Syntax Error in Join Operation in MS-Access when splitting and comparing records

Tags: sql, ms-access, split, compare, append

Above error message occurs with this statement:

```
 SELECT f.fullname INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM (
(SELECT Left([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")-1)) As lastname FROM
SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten) & " " & (SELECT
RIGHT([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")+1)) As firstname FROM
SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten) & " " & (SELECT
summary_judgment.middle_initial AS middlename FROM summary_judgment)
) AS fullname
FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten AS f INNER JOIN summary_judgment
AS s ON f.lastname = s.last_name && f.firstname = s.first_name;
```

Basically this is what two tables look like (note they will have more fields than 1 where last or first name of different fields can be similar):

```
SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten (table)
aname (field)
Leventhal,Raymond (data)


summary_judgment (table)
first_name(field)
Raymond (data)
last_name (field)
Leventhal (data)
middle_initial (field)
P (data)
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to create a new table that is like
SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten but with the middle initial from
summary_judgment appended:
Leventhal,Raymond P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT left([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")-1) & " " 
     & right([aname],Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname],",")) & " "
     & summary_judgment.middle_initial AS fullname 
INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten, summary_judgment;
```

Though you might want this instead:

```
SELECT left([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")-1) & ", " 
     & right([aname],Len(aname)-InStr(1,[aname],",")) & " "
     & summary_judgment.middle_initial AS fullname 
INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten, summary_judgment;
```

The second version gives you the comma after the last name. Note that Right counts *from* the right, which is why you have to subtract the InStr value from the length.

**EDIT:**

The code I gave above works with your sample data--one row in each table. With more rows, it gives a cross product of (LastName, FirstName) x MiddleInitial. It occurred to me that that might be the case, so I went back to my test & added a second row--it *is* true. So then I tried to write the join expression....

Access doesn't like this:

```
... ON left([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")-1) = last_name ...
```

It throws the error "Join expression not supported." Changing it to this:

```
... ON (trim((left(SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.aname,InStr(1,[aname],",")-1))=trim(summary_judgment.last_name))) ...
```

results in a query that runs & creates the table, but doesn't create any rows (the same was true before I added the "trim" calls in an attempt to fix it).

So I tried specifying the table for all occurences of aname. No joy--until I realized that I was making the wrong comparison (derived-last to last and derived-first to last--oops).

Using the following FROM clause with either above SELECT ... INTO *does* work correctly:

```
FROM 
  SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten INNER JOIN 
  summary_judgment ON 
    ((left(SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.aname,InStr(1,SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.[aname],",")-1))=summary_judgment.last_name) AND 
    ((right(SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.aname,Len(SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.aname)-InStr(1,SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten.[aname],","))=summary_judgment.first_name));
```

It might even work correctly without the full qualification of each field now that I'm joining first to first & last to last (since there is no duplication across the tables), but having proven that it does work, I'm done.

Comment: Wow! That last FROM clause you posted was the missing piece.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to write 3 select statements to concatenate the values into one field.

```
select left(...) & right(...) & initial AS fullname INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
 FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten
```

Comment: So you are saying something like this: select left([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")-1)) & right([aname],InStr(1,[aname],",")+1)) & summary_judgment.middle_initial AS fullname INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
 FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten, summary_judgment

Comment: Exactly. This is what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use two ampersands to represent a logical AND?

```
FROM SummaryJudgment_FinalForgotten AS f INNER JOIN summary_judgment
AS s ON f.lastname = s.last_name && f.firstname = s.first_name;
```

I don't think that's legal for Access' Jet/ACE database engines.  Try it with the **AND** keyword in place of **&&.**

OTOH, I wonder if you can do something simpler.

```
SELECT last_name & "," & first_name & " " & middle_initial AS fullname
INTO SummaryJudgment_FinalForgottenWithMiddle
FROM summary_judgment;
```